# JQ: How to put content of a file within another file under a certain key?

Tags: json, jq

Using **jq**, I want to

- (1) read the count of keys in `package.json` within `peerDependencies`
- (2) if the count is `0`, remove from `docs.json` when `sections[].name === 'prerequesite'`

This is how I solved (1):

```
if [[ $(cat package.json | jq '.peerDependencies | length') = 0 ]]; then
  echo "Remove page prerequesite as no peer dependencies were found"
  # do (2)
fi
```

This is how I started to solve (2):

```
cat docs.json | jq '.sections[] | select(.name != "Prerequisite")' > newSection.json
```

How can I put `newSection.json` in my file ?

Otherwise:

My array JSON look like below:

```
{
    "ignore": [
      "**/__tests__/**",
      "**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "**/*.spec.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "sections": [{
        "name": "Introduction",
        "content": "docs/introduction.md"
    }, {
        "name": "Prerequisite",
        "content": "docs/prerequisite.md"
    }]
}
```

I expect to have

```
{
    "ignore": [
      "**/__tests__/**",
      "**/*.test.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "**/*.spec.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "sections": [{
        "name": "Introduction",
        "content": "docs/introduction.md"
    }]
}
```

In my `tmp.json` file I have:

How can I remove from the array the section with name `prerequisite` using the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `select()` construct to remove the object containing the `.name` field from the JSON structure.

```
if [[ $(jq '.peerDependencies | length' package.json) = 0 ]]; then
    jq '.sections |= map(select(.name != "Prerequisite"))' docs.json      
fi
```

You can then use `> newSection.json` to re-direct the modified content of `docs.json` to the new file.